# In VimScript, How to test if a window is the last window

Tags: vim

I'v made a mapping:

```
nmap: <ESC><ESC> :close<CR>
```

But this mapping can't close the last openned window

So I plan to write a function to test if the current window is the last openned window

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I use the following to tell if the quickfix windows is the only remaining if so exiting without prompt.

```
if winbufnr(2) == -1
   quit!
endif
```

Here is my entire code from my .vimrc:

```
autocmd BufEnter * call MyLastWindow()

function! MyLastWindow()
   if &buftype=="quickfix"
      " if this window is last on screen quit without warning
      if winbufnr(2) == -1
         quit!
      endif
   endif
endfunction
```

You could modify it to simply do a close if its not the last window and do a quit! if it is.  Obviously calling it from your mapping instead of from an autocmd.

Answer (score 4):

Why not just use:

```
nmap: <ESC><ESC> :quit<CR>
```

Answer (score 3):

I see it's been mentioned in the comments, but this deserves to be presented as an answer: `winnr('$')`. From `:help winnr()`

> The result is a Number, which is the number of the current window. The top window has number 1. When the optional argument is "$", the number of the last window is returned (the window count).

So you could do,

```
if winnr('$') == 1
  " only one window
endif
```

Answer (score 1):

It has always surprised me that there isn't a native way of finding such information. I have a function that returns the number of open windows by crudely counting them using the `windo` command:

```
fun! NumWindows()
    let num_wins = 0
    windo let num_wins += 1
    return num_wins
endfun
```

So you have reached the last window when `NumWindows() == 1`.

(I think I may have stolen the `windo` idea from another thread, but I'm afraid I can't remember which.)

Comment: Come to think of it, can we search the whole Vim Help System for keyword, say maybe "buffer counting"?

Comment: You can use `:helpgrep {pattern}`, and then `:cnext` to jump through the results, but you generally have to know what you're looking for.

Comment: Are you sure that there's no native way of finding this information ? I'll wait for a while before setting your answer as correct.

Comment: @Price Goulash: Counting windows is easy with `winnr('$')`

Comment: @Peter Rincker: thanks, that's much simpler! There's always more to learn about Vim!